# open jquery dialog multiple times with same html

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have one button, on click of that button it open a Jquery ui dialog which has div inside, after that if i click on same button it should open same dialog with same div again while previous dialog still on screen. like in Windows if i click on an icon multiple times it open multiple new window each and every time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to make a copy of the elements and use it to open each new dialog.

```
$('#dialogDiv').clone().dialog(...);
```